# How can I fix QNX ldd:FATAL:Could not load library XXXX.so.0?

Tags: fatal-error, qnx

I am trying to run GoogleTestLibrary on QNX ?

But i am getting this error message?

```
ldd:FATAL: Could not load library libgtest.so.0
```

Firstly i build googtestLibrary on qnx virtual machine with make command and it genarates lib files.

And then i added these libs in qnx extra library paths. Also i added extra include file for GoogleTestLibrary. And then i build my qnx project on QNX momentics ide and it build successfully. And then i tried to run but it gave me the ldd:FATAL: Could not load library libgtest.so.0 that error.

I included all libraries into the projects but i did not get success run. Does anyone encourage the that problem?

Comment: try to add as many information to your question as possible; what's your setup, what steps did you take ...

Comment: Okay, firstly i build googtestLibrary on qnx virtual machine with make command and it genarates lib files. And then i added these libs in qnx extra library paths. Also i added extra include file for GoogleTestLibrary. And then i build my qnx project on QNX momentics ide and it build successfully. And then i tried to run but it gave me the ldd:FATAL: Could not load library libgtest.so.0 that error. @m02ph3u5

Comment: You should add that to your original question instead of the comment section so people see it at a first glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. 
I copied **libgtest.so.0** library to /usr/lib folder in target machine.

And i restarted to target machine. After that i can run my projects. Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0):

Your project built successfully so paths for libraries in IDE are right.

You have an issue with run of binary therefore try to put built libraries into directory where binary is located.

Or you may use LIBRARY_PATH variable, like this:

```
C:\> LIBRARY_PATH=C:\projects\GoogleTestLibrary\ application.exe
```